# IIF(InStr) function - Inserting data into unrelated field

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder

I have the following expression in a report field (Report Builder 1.0):

```
=IIf(InStr(Fields!AMA_WEBUSERID.Value,"support") > 0, Fields!Centre.Value = "Web", Fields!Centre.Value)
```

The expression evaluates to `True`, but another field (`Centre`) is not filled with the string `Web`. Instead it just says `False`.

Comment: Where is this being evaluated? I don't think you are capable of assigning values to other fields in this manner. Instead, you can put this expression on the `Centre` field and have the value, `Web` be returned when `support` is found in the `AMA_WEBUSERID` field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting `False` because the when `AMA_WEBUSERID` contains "support" you evaluate the Boolean expression `Fields!Centre.Value = "Web"` which returns `False`. You can't assign the value of a field in the way you are trying to. Instead, use the following formula for the `Value` property of the cell where you are displaying the field `Centre`:

```
=IIf(InStr(Fields!AMA_WEBUSERID.Value,"support") > 0, "Web", Fields!Centre.Value)
```